# Merge several tests executed trx files into a single trx file without appending the results

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, trx, test-results

I am using `TRX-Merger.exe` to merge the `*.trx` files and generate a combined one. But I am facing issue is, after the merge the results are getting duplicated(appending), like before merging the results was showing 120 passed and 20 failed, after the re-run and using `TRX-Merger.exe` want to merge the *.trx files with the final results, it will get added and it will show as **140 passed and 40 failed**. Which should be 140 passed and 0 failed.

Command I am using to merge the trx files:

```
TRX_Merger.exe /trx:[trx file or directory 1],[trx file or directory 2],..,[trx file or directory N] /output:[output file path and name]

TRX_Merger.exe /trx:c:\ci\TEST-UI.trx,c:\ci\TEST-UI_Rerun.trx /output:c:\ci\TEST-UI_Final.trx
```

So is there a mechanism to avoid this duplicates and get a Final.trx file with the proper results after the re-run.

Comment: Why do you want to merge the text results files? You could upload multiple .trx files in the test results tasks instead.

Comment: @GeralexGR Could you please help me to guide on how to do that. Coz at the end the results in the TFS pipeline should show properly, should not get increase/duplicated.